# Will enclosing the caller function and the called function inside process.nextTick make them asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Do I need to call start function from `process.nextTick` when `start` function is already inside `process.nextTick`? I want to make both the `accept` and `start` function asynchronous? What should be the desired way to achieve this?

```
function accept() { // ACCEPT FUNCTION
   process.nextTick(() => {
      start(); // START CALL
   });
}

function start() { // START FUNCTION
  process.nextTick(() => {
      startPolling();
  });
}
```

Comment: hope it helps: https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If the `startPolling()` function is blocking, then putting it in `nextTick()` callback won't help. It will block the entire thread on the next tick of the event loop - but it will block it nonetheless.

Example:

Without `nextTick`:

```
function x() {
    fs.readFileSync('file');
}
x(); // <-- it blocks here
console.log('...');
```

With `nextTick`:

```
function x() {
    pricess.nextTick(() => fs.readFileSync('file'));
}
x();
console.log('...');
// <-- it blocks here
// (end of file)
```

It doesn't actually block on the last line of the file but it is more or less what would happen - your code will keep going and as soon as there is no more code to run and the next tick of the event loop can be started, your process will block on the function and nothing will be able to happen before the `fs.readFileSync()` returns.

`process.nextTick()` is never a solution for a blocking code. It can be helpful for non-blocking code in some situations where you want to keep the execution order consistent for example, but the solution to blocking code is not using `nextTick` but rather avoiding the blocking functions (like the "Sync" functions from `fs`) altogether.

In fact, the only place where you should ever use a blocking functions (like `readFileSync()` or `require()`) is on the first tick of the event loop - and using `nextTick()` guarantees that you're not running them on the first tick.